# apt-get error installing software on Parrot OS

Tags: linux, software-installation, apt

I am trying to install **Evolution Email client** but when I run `"sudo apt-get install evolution"` I get the following errors:

```
"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
console-setup-linux : Depends: keyboard-configuration (= 1.123) but 1.88 is to be installed
evolution : Depends: libcamel-1.2-49 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libecal-1.2-16 (>= 3.5.91) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libedataserver-1.2-18 (>= 3.11.90) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libevolution (>= 3.12) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libevolution (< 3.13) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.36) but 2.33.12+really2.32.4-5 is to be installed
            Depends: libical1a (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libsoup2.4-1 (>= 2.42) but 2.38.1-3 is to be installed
            Depends: evolution-common (= 3.12.9~git20141130.241663-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: evolution-data-server (>= 3.12.9~) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: evolution-data-server (< 3.13) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: evolution-plugins but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: bogofilter but it is not going to be installed or
                        spamassassin but it is not going to be installed
libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.14) but 2.19-18 is to be installed
libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.13-38+deb7u6) but 2.19-18 is to be installed
xserver-xorg-core : Depends: libaudit0 (>= 1.7.13) but it is not going to be installed
xvfb : Depends: libaudit0 (>= 1.7.13) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)."
```

So I try to run `"sudo apt-get -f install"` and I get this error...

```
"Reading changelogs... Done
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up initscripts (2.88dsf-59) ...
insserv: script checkroot.sh: service mtab already provided!
insserv: script checkroot.sh: service mtab already provided!
insserv: script checkroot.sh: service mtab already provided!
insserv: script checkroot.sh: service mtab already provided!
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing initscripts (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
initscripts
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) "
```

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` ?

Comment: So the sources.list originally showed this... 
#cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 Kali - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20141210-17:20]/ kali contrib main non-free 
I saw it was a Kali repo so I added these...
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free

Comment: Adding the Kali repos did not help any.